# CGSizeApplyAffineTransform xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

```
_needleLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(CGSizeMake(-2.0, -2.0), affineTransform3);
```

where affineTransform3 is `CALayer.AffineTransform`

What is the equivalent of the above code in C#?

I could not find `CGSizeApplyAffineTransform` or anything similar though there is a `CoreGraphics.CGAffineTransform.CGRectApplyAffineTransform`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TransformSize` is a helper method on a `CGAffineTransform` ***instance*** that calls `CGSizeApplyAffineTransform`.

So:

```
_needleLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(CGSizeMake(-2.0, -2.0), affineTransform3);
```

Becomes:

```
_needleLayer.ShadowOffset = affineTransform3.TransformSize(new CGSize(-2f, -2f));
```

Or you can directly call `CGSizeApplyAffineTransform` if you really need too(?) via:

```
[DllImport(ObjCRuntime.Constants.CoreGraphicsLibrary)]
public extern static CGSize CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(CGSize rect, CGAffineTransform t);
```

Comment: Thanks man. Anyway how do you find these things? I sometimes lose too much time on things like these.

Comment: @HeisenBerg I keep a complete set of the generated Xamarin.iOS|Android framework on my Mac. That way I can not only search it quickly but also `diff` the changes by release version (I setup a cron job to grab the latest git branch/tag and  do a build to generated the source....). But something like this would be in the non-generated source as they are hand-written helpers in a CGAffineTransform partial class (just check out github.com/xamarin)